# Deploying Flask_restplus Api build over Flask App using uwsgi.py on nginx server

Tags: python, nginx, flask-restplus

All

I have a flask_rest plus api over flask app in python. I want to deploy the same using the uwsgi format on nginx server. I searched for quite a long but didn't found the write solution.Any leads would be helpful..

Thanks in advance.

Below is the code snippet

```
import datetime
from fileinput import filename
import json
import os

from flask import request
from flask_restplus import Resource, Api

from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
from APP.Application import app
from ApiConfig.ObjectConfig import Trainer, cData, Tmodal, Amodal, Cmodal
from ApiConfig.SA_utility import sentiment_sorting
from ApiConfig.appFileConfig import UPLOAD_FOLDER
from Classification.Classifier import classify
from DataBase.DB import db
from ExcelParser_DataFrame.Excel_Parser import ExcelDataFrame

from Vectorizer.Data_vector import vectorizer
from Mapper.UI_Map import UI_Map
from werkzeug.contrib.fixers import ProxyFix



api = Api(app)
app.wsgi_app = ProxyFix(app.wsgi_app)

@api.route('/sentiment-analysis/trainer')

class Upload_File(Resource):
    def post(self):
    ..............


if __name__ == '__main__':
    db.init_app(app)
    db.create_all()
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

My wsgi.py file looks like this

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, "/home/gulshan/Downloads/SA_PANDAS_SGDC/src")


from APP.Application import app
application = app
```

i tried using this wsgi file and started the server by firing the below command on my linux machine

```
uwsgi --http :5000 --wsgi-file wsgi.py --callable app --processes 4 --threads 2 --stats 127.0.0.1:9191
```

when i tried accessing the url using Postman then i get error as shown below:-

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>404 Not Found</title>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL was not found on the server.  If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.</p>
```

My APP.Application file looks like this:-

```
from flask import Flask
from ApiConfig import Settings as settings

app = Flask(__name__)


#app.config['SERVER_NAME'] = settings.FLASK_SERVER_NAME
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = settings.SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = settings.SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS
app.config['SWAGGER_UI_DOC_EXPANSION'] = settings.RESTPLUS_SWAGGER_UI_DOC_EXPANSION
app.config['RESTPLUS_VALIDATE'] = settings.RESTPLUS_VALIDATE
app.config['RESTPLUS_MASK_SWAGGER'] = settings.RESTPLUS_MASK_SWAGGER
app.config['ERROR_404_HELP'] = settings.RESTPLUS_ERROR_404_HELP
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_POOL_SIZE'] = settings.SQLALCHEMY_POOL_SIZE
#app.config['SQLALCHEMY_POOL_TIMEOUT'] = settings.SQLALCHEMY_POOL_TIMEOUT
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_POOL_RECYCLE'] = settings.SQLALCHEMY_POOL_RECYCLE
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_MAX_OVERFLOW'] = settings.SQLALCHEMY_MAX_OVERFLOW
```

Answer (score 0):

Got a solution working for me although it seems to be weird way of doing this:-
Changed my uwsgi.py

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, "/home/gulshan/Downloads/SA_PANDAS_SGDC/src")


from APP.Application import app
from flask import Flask
from SA_APP.SA import appnew

application = app
application = appnew
```

and added this line in my first code snippet file containing main call

```
api = Api(app)
appnew = app.
```